# How to get the values before a key and after a key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary below

```
{'1': {'Col1': 'Val1', 'Col2': 'Val2', 'output': 'Out1'},
 '2': {'Col1': 'Val1', 'Col2': 'Val2', 'output': 'Out1'},
 '3': {'Col1': 'Val1', 'Col2': 'Val2', 'output': 'Out1'},
 '4': {'Col1': 'Val1', 'Col2': 'Val2', 'output': 'Out1'}}
```

I need to get the values before the key `output`

since dictionary is unordered i have converted into below

```
              OrderedDict([('1',
              OrderedDict([('Col1', 'Val1'),
                           ('Col2', 'Val2'),
                           ('output', 'Out1')])),
             ('2',
              OrderedDict([('Col1', 'Val1'),
                           ('Col2', 'Val2'),
                           ('output', 'Out1')])),
             ('3',
              OrderedDict([('Col1', 'Val1'),
                           ('Col2', 'Val2'),
                           ('output', 'Out1')])),
             ('4',
              OrderedDict([('Col1', 'Val1'),
                           ('Col2', 'Val2'),
                           ('output', 'Out1')]))])
```

Expected out is below, need to extract the values before `output`

```
{'1': ['Val1', 'Val2'],
'2': ['Val1', 'Val2'],
'3': ['Val1', 'Val2'],
'4': ['Val1', 'Val2']}
```

Expected out is below, need to extract the values after the `output` key

```
{'1': [],
'2': [],
'3': [],
'4': []}
```

Sample dictionary for testing

```
{'1': {'Col1': 'Val1', 'output': 'Out1', 'test': 'Out1'},
 '2': {'Col1': 'Val1', 'output': 'Out1', 'test': 'Out1'},
 '3': {'Col1': 'Val1','output': 'Out1'},
 '4': {'Col1': 'Val1', 'output': 'Out1'}}
```

Expected out is below, need to extract the values before `output`

```
{'1': ['Val1'],
'2': ['Val1'],
'3': ['Val1'],
'4': ['Val1']}
```

Expected out is below, need to extract the values after the `output` key

```
{'1': ['Out1'],
'2': ['Out1'],
'3': [],
'4': []}
```

Comment: Just a note, since Python 3.7 dicts are guaranteed to maintain *insertion* order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over items using an iterator and appending to `before` list.  When the key you are looking for is found, `break` from that loop and then iterate again using that same iterator to read the values for the `after` list.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict([('1',
                  OrderedDict([('Col1', 'Val1'),
                               ('Col2', 'Val2'),
                               ('output', 'Out1')])),
                 ('2',
                  OrderedDict([('Col1', 'Val1'),
                               ('Col2', 'Val2'),
                               ('output', 'Out1')])),
                 ('3',
                  OrderedDict([('Col1', 'Val1'),
                               ('Col2', 'Val2'),
                               ('output', 'Out1')])),
                 ('4',
                  OrderedDict([('Col1', 'Val1'),
                               ('Col2', 'Val2'),
                               ('output', 'Out1')]))])

def vals_before_and_after(od, key):
    it = iter(od.items())
    before_vals = []
    for k, v in it:
        if k == key:
            break
        before_vals.append(v)
    after_vals = [v for k, v in it]
    return before_vals, after_vals

before = OrderedDict()
after = OrderedDict()
for k, v in d.items():
    before[k], after[k] = vals_before_and_after(v, 'output')

print(before)
print(after)
```

Gives:

```
OrderedDict([('1', ['Val1', 'Val2']), ('2', ['Val1', 'Val2']), ('3', ['Val1', 'Val2']), ('4', ['Val1', 'Val2'])])
OrderedDict([('1', []), ('2', []), ('3', []), ('4', [])])
```

You might also raise an exception if the key you are looking for is never found (`break` never executed). For example:

```
    ...
    for k, v in it:
        if k == key:
            break
        before_vals.append(v)
    else:
        raise RuntimeError(f'The key {key} was not found')
    ...
```

Comment: why we are using break here can you tell the logic

Comment: after_vals = [v for k, v in it], how its appending in after_vals  ?

Comment: @aysh `break` will terminate early from the execution of the loop - you have finished finding the "before" items once you find the 'output' key, so you do not iterate over the items until they are exhausted; then when you iterate again, there will be more items still to read

Comment: With `after_vals`, I could have used a `for` loop very similar to the `before_vals` one, but without the conditional `break`. It was just a bit more concise to use a list comprehension, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dict comprehension:

```
dx = {k: list({i:x for i, x in v.items() if x != 'Out1'}.values()) for k,v in d.items()}

print(dx)

{'1': ['Val1', 'Val2'],
 '2': ['Val1', 'Val2'],
 '3': ['Val1', 'Val2'],
 '4': ['Val1', 'Val2']}
```

Comment: is there any way i can pop out everything after output key

Comment: I have added one sample dictionary for testng

Comment: Why is `'Out1'` hardcoded in this? The breaking point is the *key* `'output'`.